# Rails add required=>true in select_tag of form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I want to show a "This field is required" if a person has not selected any option in options field.I am trying to make **:required => true** work.
Please find below the code line. Also if there is no direct way it would be great if someone can point out to any java script which can be used in onChange callback to make things work.

```
<%=  select_tag('params[type]', 
                options_for_select({"abc" => "ABC","xyz" => "XYZ}, nil),
                :required => true , 
                :class => "fk-select-box",
                :multiple => true, 
                :tabindex => "4",
                :prompt => "Select Type") %>
```

Comment: and not the `required=>true` isn't work?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do? Are you getting any error? Please describe your question in detail.

Comment: Paste your form code

Comment: Problem is that even if the option is not selected i.e. is null , the code still sends a request to controller. I want to catch any required field not filled in form itself

Answer (score 0):

You can pass javascript function like this on change event of select box,

```
function Change_selectbox()
{
var selectboxid = document.getElementsByClassName("Selectboxid")[0];
var selectboxchange = selectboxid.options[selectboxid.selectedIndex].value;

if (selectboxchange === "nil")
  {
      document.getElementById("errors_span_id").innerHTML=("<center>This field is required");
      document.getElementsByClassName("selectboxid")[0].focus();
      return false;
  }
}
```

Other best option you should use model validation.